# knockout blinking elements - any alternative to style="display:none"

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I'm using knockout to display elements. Here is the simple example:

**HTML**

```
<p data-bind="text:userName, visible:userLoggedIn"></p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
    background:green;
}
```

**JS**

```
var vm = {
    userName:ko.observable('peter'),
    userLoggedIn:ko.observable(false)
}

ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

The problem is that it takes some time for knockout to figure out that element is not to be shown and hide it with `display:none`. This period of time is pretty short (less than a second depending on a page complexity), however it doesn't look good when elements blink.
I can't make element initially `display:none` in CSS, since for some reason knockout cannot override that style with `display:block`. The only solution I know of is to put inline style on the element `style="display:none"`. Are there any other alternatives to this approach?

Comment: What is the problem with the inline style? But generally you cannot do this the visible binding, you need your custom binding or you the style or the css bindings: http://jsfiddle.net/Hd5B4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout adds a dynamic style display element when 'visible' is false and removes it when visible is true. That's why the display:none in css is kicking back in and your element is never shown.

You need to change it to a css binding like so

**HTML**

```
<p data-bind="text:userName, css:isDisplayed"></p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
    background:green;
    display: none;
}

.shown{
    display: block;
}
```

**KNOCKOUT**

```
var vm = {
    userName:ko.observable('peter'),
    userLoggedIn:ko.observable(true) 
}

vm.isDisplayed = ko.computed(function(){
    return this.userLoggedIn() ? "shown" : "";
}, vm);

ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

note the computed function which adds the shown class to override the CSS.

Here's a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Ky4EM/

Hope this helps